# A question about how to take a -1 out of mutiple-valued analytic function $z^{\alpha } $ $0<\alpha<1 $

Tags: complex-analysis

I encountered a question about multiple-valued analytic functions.

Under some circumstance I have to take a -1 out of a power function $z^{\alpha } $          $0<\alpha<1$

suppose $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, let the branch cut be $[0,\infty ]$, choose the analytic branch $z^{\frac{1}{2}}(1^{\frac{1}{2}}=1)$, and I get two following result they are $$z^{\frac{1}{2}}=((-1)(-z))^{\frac{1}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=i(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ 
and

$$z^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\frac{1}{-1}(-z))^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\frac{1}{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{i}(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=-i(-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Which manipulation is right, why? How about $z^{-\frac{1}{2}}$? Is it the same?

Comment: I think what you are asking is this: is $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $z^\alpha$ is $e^{\alpha \log z}$, so let's look at 
$\log(-z)$.  If your branch cut for the logarithm (and thus also for the $\alpha$ power) is on the positive real axis,
with real limits as you approach that axis from above, i.e. you're using the branch where $0 \le \text{Im} \log(z) < 2 \pi$, then 
$\log(-z) = \log(z) + \pi i$ if $0 \le \text{Im} \log(z) < \pi$ (i.e. $z$ is on  the positive real axis or in the upper half plane),
$\log(z) - \pi i$ if $z$ is on the negative real axis or in the lower half plane.
And so
$ (-z)^\alpha = e^{i\alpha \pi + \alpha \log z} = e^{i\alpha \pi} z^\alpha$ if 
$z$ is on the positive real axis or in the upper half plane, 
$e^{-i \alpha \pi} z^\alpha$ if $z$ is on the negative real axis or in the lower half plane.

Comment: So when consider a value of the logarithm or power, it's better to return to the definition and examine the argument change？